# Controlling access to Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I have two web forms created using ASP .NET.

One is a login web form, the other displays information.

When a user successfully logs in the login form redirects them to the other web form.

How do I stop a user from typing in the name of the web form in the URL i.e. control access to certain pages.

My aim is to have a user login, and only if they are logged in, may they access the other form.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can find some answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910699/quickest-way-to-require-authentication-in-asp-net-webform

Comment: Another quick fix will be to set the valid user state to a session variable and include an ascx page in all inside pages. There you can always check the session variable and redirect if not a valid session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a few ways to do this.

The way that I have done it in the past is to create a CurrentUser singleton class that is populated with user information at login and persisted in the session (Although a simple Session["LoggedIn"] = true would also do the job - the class will allow you to store more information including the users roles etc in one place making them easily accessible.

You then create a class such as this (Excuse the pseudo code)

```
public class SecureBase : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override OnLoad(Event Args etc...)
    {
        if (!CurrentUser.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/uh-uh-uh--You-didnt-say-the-magic-word.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

You then make any pages that you want to be secure inherit from this rather than directly from System.Web.UI.Page :

```
public class HomePage : Page
{...}
```

becomes

```
public class HomePage : SecureBase
{...}
```

And your done, anyone not logged in will get redirected any one else will carry on as normal.